# Typical IT projects in Investment banks middle office and back office

Tags: business-process-management

Currently working as a business systems analyst and interested to work in an investment bank. So can someone please help me to understand typical IT project processes that can exists in middle and front offices in investment banks. Any uses case links would help a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming related question but rather a Project Management question. I suggest posting it on https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming related question but rather a Project Management question.